# Class not found when setting custom class when using custom logging

Tags: kubernetes, logging, apache-superset

**Using superset on kubernetes, I would like to modify the events logged on the standard output.**

In the [documentation](https://apache-superset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#event-logging) there's a python class that can be used to modify the logger.
In the chart's values I've set :

```
extraConfigFiles:
  stats_logger.py: |-
    class JSONStdOutEventLogger(AbstractEventLogger):
      def log(self, user_id, action, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

And

```
configFile: |-
   ...
  EVENT_LOGGER = JSONStdOutEventLogger()
   ...
```

Unfortunalty the pod doesn't find the class:

```
NameError: name 'JSONStdOutEventLogger' is not defined
```

There's no documentation beside that so I'm lost in the dark abyss of event logging...

Help would be greatly appreciated ! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Superset doesn't give any clue but in my case I had to import `AbstractEventLogger` and `json`.

Just put these two lines above your `JSONStdOutEventLogger` class :

```
from superset.utils.log import AbstractEventLogger
import json
```